# Pandas join two tables but not sure with which column in df2 ('or' syntax?)

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I would like to join two tables together. Both tables are very large (around 1m rows). The problem is, It's not always clear which row the join needs to be made to. Ideally the program should try to join with col_x and if that fails try col_y

I would need to do an or logic as follows:

```
df3=pd.merge(df1,df2,left_on'col1', right_on='col_x' or 'col_y', how='left')
```

Any suggestions how this is best implemented are appreciated.

Comment: How do you determine which column should be used, simply when the merge of the table fails using col_x?

Comment: If col_x is empty, then it should try col_y

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a new column that contains the values you want to merge on first. Haven't tested, but I think it would be something like

```
# first create new column
df2['merge_col'] = df2['col_x']

# replace empty values
empty_rows = df2['merge_col'].isnull()
df2.loc[empty_rows, 'merge_col'] = df2.loc[empty_rows, 'col_y']

# merge with the new column
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on='col1', right_on='merge_col', how='left')
```

Comment: this is actually a much better idea than what I had in mind.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried something like the below or do you require the check to be done within the merge function?

```
if df3["col_x"] == "":
    df3=pd.merge(df1,df2,left_on'col1', right_on='col_y', how='left')
else:
    df3=pd.merge(df1,df2,left_on'col1', right_on='col_x', how='left')
```

Comment: I meant if df2["col_x"]<>"" 
df3 has no values before the merger. Would this still work?

Comment: It should! If the entire column is empty, then `if df2["col_x"] == ""` should return `True`. However, as long as one value exists, this will not work.

Comment: It's not the entire column that will be empty, but only some rows. For the ones where df1['col_x'] is empty, the merger should be done via col_y

Comment: then apply this logic to the individual rows. However, this may take significantly longer than simply checking the column.

Comment: That's exactly my problem, how would I best do that?